# Attach JavaScript event handler to Zend_Form_Element

Tags: zend-framework

I need to attach some javascript to the onchange event of the Zend_Form_Element. How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with setAttrib($name, $value), for example:

```
$element->setAttrib('onchange', 'jsFunction();');
```

You can find more detailed information about Zend_Form_Element's [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.elements.html).